# Android Studio Error: 2 files found with path ‘kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins’

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I’m working on an Android project using Kotlin and I’ve encountered an issue that I can’t seem to resolve. When I try to build my project, I get the following error:

```
2 files found with path 'kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins'.
Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
for more information
```

The error suggests that there are two files with the same path being included in my build, and that adding a packagingOptions block might help.

I’ve tried adding the suggested block to my build.gradle.kts file, but the error persists.

Here’s the relevant part of my build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    // ...
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
            excludes += "kotlin/reflect/reflect.kotlin_builtins"
        }
    }
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.8.10")
    // ...
}
```

I’ve also tried updating my dependencies to the latest versions, but the error still occurs. I’m not sure what else to try at this point, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Please keep in mind i'm a newbie so perhaps i am missing something. Thanks in advance